# Multiple grid header have to set using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

if we have grid like

```
me.grid=[{
 title:[a],
 header:[b,c,d,e],
 total:[x,y,z]
},
{
 title:[b],
 header:[b1,c1,d1,e1],
 total:[x,y,z]    
}

{
 title:[c],
 header:[b2,c2,d2,e2],
 total:[x,y,z]    
}
];
```

now,I only want to fetch title element using javascript or Jquery.

Comment: title:[a] --> [a] is array ??? where is it defined ??

Comment: it define in grid only,we can say it array of array

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all your Array / Object is missing a `,`:

```
me.grid = [{
    title: [a],
    header: [b, c, d, e],
    total: [x, y, z]
}, {
    title: [b],
    header: [b1, c1, d1, e1],
    total: [x, y, z]
}, {
    title: [c],
    header: [b2, c2, d2, e2],
    total: [x, y, z]
}];
```

And if you have defined all the variables you should be able to get the title element like : `me.grid[0].title`, `me.grid[1].title` and `me.grid[2].title`.

No need for jQuery, plain JavaScript will do.

Answer (score 0):

if grid is array:

```
var grid = Array({
 title:'a1',
 header:('b','c','d','e'),
 total:('x','y','z')
},
{
 title:'a2',
 header:('b','c','d','e'),
 total:('x','y','z')
},
{
 title:'a3',
 header:('b','c','d','e'),
 total:('x','y','z')
});

for(i=0; i<grid.length; i++){
    alert(grid[i].title);
}
```

[look this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7wpP/)

Answer (score 0):

```
me.grid = [{..}, {..}, {..}];
```

missing comma here------>^^^

**js**

```
$.each(me_grid, function (i, val) {
    console.log(me_grid[i].title);
});
```